# Getting data from custom defined element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I'm integrating editor-widget (custom defined component) into my react app and have faced with the problem of getting back data from this widget. Maybe you know how to do it?

widget.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Editor from "./editor";

class EditorWidget extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["md", "description"];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name == "md") {
      if (this.r) {
        this.r.render(React.cloneElement(this.widget, { md: newValue }));
      }
    } else {
      console.log(name, newValue);
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.widget = (<Editor />);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.r = ReactDOM.createRoot(this);
    this.r.render(React.cloneElement(this.widget, {
      md: this.getAttribute("md"),
      getContent: (val) => {this.setAttribute("description", val); console.log(val);}
    }));
  }
}

customElements.define("widget", EditorWidget);
```

In main.jsx I call element like this:

```
//description value declaration
const [description, setDescription] = useState()
//widget declaration
<widget
   md={"test"}
   description={setDescription}
/>
```

Also should notice that at the beginning "test" word appears and at every console.log(val) or  console.log(newValue) I can see inputed data